# How to get dynamic view to update properly when scope variable changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developing an Angular SPA and on one view there is a `$scope` variable that determines the majority of the content for that page.  If the user clicks on a different link in a menu, the parameters will be passed through the url, and the scope variable gets updated. However, when doing this, the view does not get updated.  I generally don't ask questions on here, but I have tried what seems like everything, and can't figure out why the view isn't being updated. Here is what the code looks like:

html

```
<div ng-init="loadTopicView()">
    <h1 ng-bind="selectedTopic.title"></h1>
    <p ng-bind="selectedTopic.body"></p>
</div>
```

js

```
$scope.loadTopicView = function() {
    var selectedTopic  = urlParams.index;
    $scope.selectedTopic = $scope.topics[selectedTopic];
}
```

Initially, I thought because of the way it was being called the `$scope.selectedTopic` wasn't getting the correct value, like the url didn't have the value yet. `$scope.topics` is an array of objects and which ever link the user clicks on will pass an index through the url and then assign the correct object to the `$scope.selectedTopic`.

After trying many things, I even tried running it over and over to see if it would make a difference using `window.setInterval` but it didn't change the fact that for some reason the html isn't updating.

I've seen issues like this before, with boolean values and ng-show but I can't figure this one out. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

More Info as requested:

Here is the html for the side nav that selects what content will be showed on the page

```
<ul class="sidebar-nav">
    <li ng-repeat="topic in topics">
        <a href="" ng-click="loadPage('/topics', topic.id)" ng-bind="topic.title"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the javascript for `$scope.loadPage`

```
$scope.loadPage = function(path, passedParams) {
    // at this point, `path` is going to the /topics view, and the `passedParams` has the id for the topic to load, lets say it is the integer: 5.

    if(path === $location.path() && path == '/topics') { // If you're switching topics but staying on the topic page
        if (!passedParams) {
            $state.reload(); // Meaning just refresh the page, no topic was selected.
        } else {
            $location.path(path).search({params: passedParams}); 
            $rootScope.$emit("CallingTopicUpdate", {});
        }
    } else { // This works fine in loading the correct topic, it is only when you are already on the topic page (so the above if), that it won't load the scope changes.
        if (passedParams) {
            $location.path(path).search({params: passedParams});
        } else {
            $location.path(path);
        }
    }
};
```

oh and this is in the same controller as the `$scope.loadTopicView`

```
$rootScope.$on("CallingTopicUpdate", function(){
    $scope.loadTopicView();
});
```

**Using `$emit` and `$on` so that when a different topic is selected while on the topic page, it will run this function again. But this is where, it updates the `$scope.selectedTopic` but the change isn't made manifest in the data that is loaded on the screen.**

As a result, you can see the params (an integer representing a topic), change in the url, but the page view that is dynamically binding data depending on the topic doesn't switch to the item you selected until you select another topic.  In essence, if you keep selecting topics, the url is right, and the view is one topic behind the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.loadTopicView = function(param) {
          var selectedTopic  = param ? param : 1;
          $scope.selectedTopic = $scope.topics.filter(function(value){return value.id==selectedTopic; });
};
$scope.loadPage = function(path, passedParams) {
              // at this point, `path` is going to the /topics view, and the `passedParams` has the id for the topic to load, lets say it is the integer: 5.
              if(path === $location.path() && path == '/topics') { // If you're switching topics but staying on the topic page
                  if (!passedParams) {
                      $state.reload(); // Meaning just refresh the page, no topic was selected.
                  } else {
                      $location.path(path).search({params: passedParams}); 
                      $rootScope.$emit("CallingTopicUpdate", passedParams);
                  }
              } else { // This works fine in loading the correct topic, it is only when you are already on the topic page (so the above if), that it won't load the scope changes.
                  if (passedParams) {
                      $location.path(path).search({params: passedParams});
                  } else {
                      $location.path(path);
                  }
              }
};
$rootScope.$on("CallingTopicUpdate", function(event, param){
            $scope.loadTopicView(param);
});
```

Comment: thank you so much for answering!  I'm trying to incorporate this to see how it works, but I'm having some trouble understanding it.  So, I only have 1 html page that I'm including, `topicView.html`...but, the data on it will change dynamically for about 100 different options. Based on the one selected, the page should show the date for just that one. I don't really understand the switch statement in the directive and what the different urls could be.

Comment: @Anguna ..may be i misunderstood the scenario. In my directive example, i am using ng-include, specifying the path of the html file to be rendered inside the div.  And dynamically loading the html based on the switch condition

Comment: Could you please share your menu links html..how you are passing the urlparams?

Comment: Alright, I just added a fair bit to the question's content for you. Hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: i have created plunkr. could you please try this [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/q8KMaGfAvXT7jyAJOHkO?p=preview)

Comment: @Anguna please let me know if this applicable in our scenario

Comment: Thank you so much!  Using the way you coded the loadTopicView worked.  Thank you so, soooo much!

Comment: Thats great!..happy coding